# Would like to use Tor with _and_ without proxy --> unexpectedly ends program

Tags: proxy, settings

I am using my laptop at home (with proxy) and outside my home (without proxy).
I have set Tor to use proxy.
Then, of course, when I am not at home, it cannot connect to the network.
No problem so far.
The problem is, however, that I do not know how to change the settings. 
The window "Connecting to Tor network" closes too quickly for me to click on "Open settings". 
Then the window "Tor network settings" appears, but it only has the options "Restart Tor", "Contact torproject.org/about/contact.html#support [not a button]), "Copy log to clipboard", "Next", and "Close". (Please excuse me if I do not have the exact names, I am using Tor with German.)

Here are my questions: What do I have to do to be able to use Tor both at home and outside my home? Where can I set the settings so Tor knows not to search for a proxy?

Thank you in advance,

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser's use of an upstream proxy is configured through Tor Button.

Click on the Green Onion menu then select Tor Network Settings.

From there you should be able to control Tor's use of an upstream proxy and pluggable transports by ticking or unticking the appropriate options and filling in the forms they toggle.

Comment: Like I said, Tor does not open. Therefore there is no Onion I can click on. Only the options "Connecting to Tor network"  "Open settings"."Tor network settings" appears, but it only has the options "Restart Tor", "Contact torproject.org/about/contact.html#support [not a button]), "Copy log to clipboard", "Next", and "Close" are available.

Comment: If it's saying "restart tor", it sounds like the Tor process is crashing. Check your operating system logs and antivirus.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The Tor process works fine when I am using my proxy, so I guess a search in the OS logs and antivirus do not make sense, or am I wrong?

Comment: In the absense of Tor logs, theres very little else to go on.

Comment: I have used the opportunity to access the settings while using my proxy and setting them to "not using a proxy".
Now it should work in both situations, with and without a proxy.
Is that smart?